# Reinstalled ros2 and all my setup.bash files are missing!

Tags: ros2

I am completely stumped with this. I had just posted a related question about autoremove and was trying to reinstall ros, I followed this guide on removing ROS2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANWHO_-FKlU and reinstalled ros-humble-desktop and all I have in /opt/ros/humble now are the directories: bin  include  lib  local  opt  share

Where are the setup and configuration files?? How do I get them? I've done this twice now and I don't know why this is happening?

I managed to run ros2 but now I get a bunch of errors running "ros2" I tried reinstalling the ones I could but now I am stuck again. Is there a way to repair my clearly broken ros2 install

```
Failed to load entry point 'doctor': librcl_action.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
The C extension '/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/_rclpy_pybind11.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so' failed to be imported while being present on the system. Please refer to 'https://docs.ros.org/en/{distro}/Guides/Installation-Troubleshooting.html#import-failing-even-with-library-present-on-the-system' for possible solutions
Failed to load entry point 'wtf': librcl_action.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
The C extension '/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/_rclpy_pybind11.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so' failed to be imported while being present on the system. Please refer to 'https://docs.ros.org/en/{distro}/Guides/Installation-Troubleshooting.html#import-failing-even-with-library-present-on-the-system' for possible solutions
```

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-humble-ros-workspace